# How to write a JSON file with a list of discord.js statuses and import it into the main JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

```
const statuses = [
 { name: "ABC", type: ActivityType.Streaming },
 { name: "DEF", type: ActivityType.Watching },
 { name: "GHI", type: ActivityType.Listening },
 { name: "JKL", type: ActivityType.Playing },
];
client.on('ready', (c) => {
  console.log(`✅ ${c.user.tag} is online!`);
  setInterval(() => {
    var newStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
    client.user.setActivity(newStatus);
  }, 10000);
});
```

*statuses.json*

(nothing, so far)

I tried adding a JSON file (a random example shown below):

```
[{
name: "ABC", type: ActivityType.Streaming
name: "DEF", type: ActivityType.Watching 
name: "GHI", type: ActivityType.Listening
name: "JKL", type: ActivityType.Playing 
}]
```

But yet, I am still not sure how to call this into my main index.js file.

Comment: [read the file](https://nodejs.org/en/learn/manipulating-files/reading-files-with-nodejs)?

Comment: Your last example is not valid JSON as posted - but is perhaps a valid JavaScript object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `statuses.json` file in the same folder like this:
(The numbers are enums for the [ActivityType](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType))

```json
[
 { "name": "ABC", "type": 1 },
 { "name": "DEF", "type": 3 },
 { "name": "GHI", "type": 2 },
 { "name": "JKL", "type": 0 }
]
```

Then in your code import your .json file:

```js
const statuses = require('./statuses.json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.json` file with the information for example like this: `[{name: "Orange", type: "fruit"}]`.

Then import using `FS` in the main `.js` file like this:

```js
const fruits = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('fruits.json'));
```

Comment: Would it be possible to write out the JSON file? Thanks.

Comment: You simply have to create a json file with the name you want with the same structure as your "statuses" variable and then import it using the name you gave it with FS